# A $2\times2$ Matrix inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant

$M,N$ are  $2\times2$ real matrices, and $MN=NM$. Then, for any three real numbers $x,y,z$, we have

$$4xz\det(xM^2+yMN+zN^2)\geq(4xz-y^2)\big(x\det(M)-z\det(N)\big)^2 $$

some thought:

1). calculate directly, we got
 $$ \det(A-xB)=x^2\det(B)-\big(\operatorname{Tr}(A)\operatorname{Tr}(B)-\operatorname{Tr}(AB)\big)x+\det(A) $$ 
(where $A,B$ are $2\times2$  matrices).

2). $ 4xz\cdot \det(xM^2+yMN+zN^2)= 4x^3z\cdot \det(M-mN)\det(M-nN) $

But I don't know how to go ahead. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you explain how you got the identity $\operatorname{det}(A-xB) = x^2\operatorname{det}(B)-\big(\operatorname{Tr}(A) \operatorname{Tr}(B) - \operatorname{Tr}(AB)\big)x + \operatorname{det}(A)$?

Comment: @MusséRedi     calculate directly

Comment: Here's one way to proceed. Observe: (a) The set of diagonalizable matrices is dense in the set of all matrices. Thus, it's sufficient to prove the inequality for *diagonalizable* matrices. (b) Commuting matrices have the same eignvectors (same eigenspaces). Combining this with (a) shows it's sufficient to prove the inequality for *diagonal* matrices $M$ and $N$. That seems like a big simplification, but I haven't worked through the details, so maybe it's still hard to prove even for diagonal $M$ and $N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the OP revealed the origin of the question, I might be able to devise a nicer solution. For the time being, I can only solve the problem by a brute-force approach. As $M$ and $N$ commute, there are only three possibilities:

1. At least one of the two matrices is nonsingular. When $M$ is nonsingular, the inequality is equivalent to
   $$4xz \det(xI + yNM^{-1} + z(NM^{-1})^2) \ge (4xz-y^2) (x-z \det(NM^{-1}))^2.$$
   So, we may assume that $M=I$. The inequality then becomes
   $$4xz\det(xI + yN + zN^2) \ge (4xz-y^2) (x-z \det(N))^2.$$
   One can verify that the difference between the two sides is equal to $\left[(x+z\det(N))y + 2xz\operatorname{trace}(N)\right]^2$. Hence the inequality holds.
2. $M,N$ are singular and diagonalisable. We may assume that $M=\operatorname{diag}(m,0)$ and $N=\operatorname{diag}(0,n)$ or $\operatorname{diag}(n,0)$ for some $m,n\in\mathbb R$. When $N=\operatorname{diag}(0,n)$, the inequality reduces to $4x^2z^2m^2n^2\ge0$; when $N=\operatorname{diag}(n,0)$, the inequality reduces to $0\ge0$.
3. $M$ and $N$ are nilpotent matrices. We may assume that they are both scalar multiples of $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$. The inequality then reduces to $0\ge0$.

I must stress that this answer is rather unsatisfactory, as it does not really explain how the inequality arises. I hope someone can come up with a more revealing answer.

Comment: It's really sufficient to show for non-singular $M$. If the inequality failed for some singular $M$, then it would have to fail for all matrices $M'$ that are sufficiently close to $M$, and some of those matrices are non-singular. In my opinion, that that makes the proof nicer.

Comment: @WillNelson If we use a continuity argument, we need to explain why, in any small neighbourhood of any pair of commuting singular $M,N$, there is always a pair of **commuting** $M',N'$ such that at least one of them is nonsingular. Since the matrices are only 2x2, explicit construction of $M',N'$ should not be too hard. But if I do so, I believe the answer would become longer than its present form. So I finally opted to consider the singular case separately, without using a continuity argument.

Comment: I don't know the origin of the question. I found it when surfing on the Internet

Comment: Thanks! How did you verify $$4xz\det(xI + yN + zN^2) - (4xz-y^2) (x-z \det(N))^2 = \left[(x+z\det(N))y + 2xz\operatorname{trace}(N)\right]^2 $$

Comment: @ziangchen Just calculate both sides in terms of the entries of $N$.

Comment: @user1551 Good point about the continuity argument. But you can just take $M'=M+\epsilon I$ and $N'=N+\epsilon I$. They'll commute and be non-singular for some arbitrarily small $\epsilon$.

Comment: @WillNelson Ah, you are right! Stupid me. :)